# Corner fill issue, Corner has fill from stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, fill

I have an issue of one corner of my shape being filled with colour from the stroke.
The brush is basic, uniform, no calligraphy brush. It happens when I close a shape. There can be fill or no fill and it still happens. Sometimes when I move the shape around on the artboard, it disappears, but this isn't a solve as I need the shape in a certain spot.

If I change the brush to Round 1Pt, no variation, the filled corner disappears but the line is not uniform, it becomes wider in some places.

Any Ideas? TIA

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't replicate the problem. Perhaps try switching to CPU preview. Could be a GPU glitch. Update your graphics driver, etc.

Comment: Switching to CPU preview it disappeared. Toggling between the views it comes and goes. Thank you

Comment: What happens if you export a PDF while the glitch is showing? Does it appear in the PDF as well, or is it only in Illustrator itself?

Comment: Only in illustrator itself, if I save a PDF and open in Acrobat it's not there. Must be a viewing glitch.